# Gender/sex in Simone de Beauvoir's "One is not born, but becomes a woman"

Tags: transsexuality

Does  Simone de Beauvoir famous claim that "One is not born, but becomes a woman" have anything to do with gender ideology? Is there some connection to the gender/sex split or to trans-identities? Has she even made any connection between her work ans trans-ideology?

Comment: People are born with either male or female reproductive organs. All the behavior regarding these organs is dictated by society. So, all this behavior is really a choice and nothing to do with the biological function of these organs and this is what de Beauvoir believed.

Comment: you seem, correct me if i'm wrong, to be implying that there are certain things you have to do and do well to be a "woman" or a "man", and idt that's what is meant here

Comment: Probably the connection was not intended, but raises from the common confusion...

Comment: I am no gynecologist/anatomist, @IdiosyncraticSoul, but I think some would object. (Regarding organs) ... regarding "society dictate", hmmhm not sure, this would be a very pious/very frivolous society ... - not my society!:) (In ant/bees/apes society it is quite clear whose dictate.)

Comment: it's a very common reactionary idea, i agree @xerx593 just another way to reproduce other forms of privilege

Comment: @xerx593 My comment was very simplistic. De Beauvoir believed in sex-gender distinction.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not certain what you mean by the phrase 'gender ideology' (that's not a label I've seen before), but de Beauvoir did the bulk of her writing even before the feminist movement began, much less the beginnings of transgender identity debates. Her philosophy was influential in the first (and indirectly influential in the second as well, I imagine), but her point was more philosophical and sociological than psychological. In brief, she was suggesting that societies have historically treated 'maleness' as the norm — e.g., the way we might conventionally talk about human beings as "our fellow men" or "mankind" — and that women were thus treated as 'other' and 'inferior'. The phrase is meant to suggest that there are no significant differences in potential between a male child and a female child, but that societies consistently treat the two differentially, limiting a female child's ability to express her potential. To become a woman in a society's eyes is to be restricted from the (normal) things that men do.

Comment: [First wave feminism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-wave_feminism) started in the late 19th, early 20th century (18th century if we consider authors like Olympe de Gouge to be part of the movement). It's innacurate to say de Beauvoir did the bulk of her writing before the feminist movement began. Are you referencing to second wave feminism?

Comment: @armand: Well… I'd typically argue that 'first wave' feminism is a retroactive category adopted in the 1960s/70s, when the Women's Liberation movement really took off. The term (as far as I can tell) was not used in the modern sense before that, when women were mainly focused on suffrage. But if you prefer that terminology, then yes.

Comment: the term "feminism" was coined [in the 19th century](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feminism#:~:text=Charles%20Fourier%2C%20a%20utopian%20socialist,the%20United%20States%20in%201910.)... Of course first wave feminists didn't call themselves "first wave". Because at the time they had no idea there would be a second one.

Comment: @armand: The term 'feminist' was used in the 19th century to mean "showing feminine qualities". It wasn't applied as the label for a movement until the mid-20th century (otherwise de Beauvoir would have used it herself). Words change meaning over time. Note: I'm not disagreeing with your point, just disputing language.

Comment: No it was used to describe women fighting to have more rights (look at the link). So there was such movements we would now call "feminist", and they indeed called themselves "feminist". Feminism existed long before Beauvoir's birth, let alone work. Sorry to nitpick your answer is great otherwise, but you're flat wrong on this one.

Answer (score 2):

I would say the connection is clear, but not direct:

DeBeauvoir was one of the first major figures to posit that "gender" is a social construct. In other words, *There may be physical realities associated with gender, but the majority of what we associate with "male" or "female" is by social consensus, and could be constructed or construed differently*. To use a trivial example, in the recent American imagination, "pink" is an intrinsically female color, "blue" is male (as immortalized in innumerable gender-reveal parties), but other cultures and times have reversed that connection, taking "pink" as male and "blue" as female. DeBeauvoir's view aligns with the larger Existentialist philosophical movement, which denies the ability of outside forces to impose upon the primacy of personal expression and identity.

Since this contradicts prior beliefs--*that there are immutable biological realities, and gender is one of them*--in this way it paved the way for the modern belief that gender is something capable of being changed. However, there does exist tension between the idea that gender is purely socially constructed, and the argument that some people are born with a gender that does not match their physical traits, but that is nonetheless immutable.

Comment: Any reference to DeBeauvoir having a concept of gender in the modern sense at all when writing in the 40s? Afaik that use was practically unheard of prior to the late 60s, but I haven't read her.

Comment: @gs I'd say rather that she helped *create* the modern concept of gender, or at least foreshadow it.